# Active Admin has_many dynamic forms

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

How can I set up has_many relations for Active Admin?

I have several models:

```
Category <--->> Case <--->> Question <--->> Answer
                     <--->> Key
```

Could not find any documentation on Active Admin which could point how to create nested forms for has_many relation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to accomplish this task using `form` method, however it would be interesting to know whether any automatic solution (like django admin) exists :)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Case do
  menu :priority => 3

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :id
    column :title do |test_case|
      link_to test_case.title, [:admin, test_case]
    end
    column :category
    default_actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :category
      f.input :title
    end

    f.inputs "Questions" do
      f.has_many :questions do |question_f|
        question_f.input :body

        question_f.inputs "Answers" do
          question_f.has_many :answers do |answer_f|
            answer_f.input :body
          end
        end

      end
    end

    f.inputs "Keys" do
      f.has_many :keys do |key_f|
        key_f.input :prevalent_answer
        key_f.input :body
      end
    end

    f.buttons
  end
end
```